# Dictionary replace "None" by in value nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a dictionary looking like this:

```
nested_dict = { 'dictA': {'text': "ok",'useleskey':'useles_value','confidence': "lol"},
                'dictB':  None, 
                'dictC':  None, }
```

Every dictionary can be filled (like `dictA`) or have `None` value.

I want to create a new list for each dictionary to summarize important information I can get.

Pseudo code for non-null dictionary look like this:

```
list_dict_A= [nested_dict["dictA"]["text"], nested_dict["dictA"]["confidence"]]
```

If the dictionary is `None`, then I want to create the following list

```
list_dict_B=[0, 0]
```

So with this example, the expected outcome will be 3 list having the following values:

```
list_dict_A=["ok", "lol"]
list_dict_B=[0, 0]
list_dict_C=[0, 0]
```

Comment: This can be easily done by iterating over keys of nested_dict and based on the value the corresponding results can be added to the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using dict comprehension:

```
nested_dict = {'dictA': {'text': "ok", 'useleskey': 'useles_value', 'confidence': "lol"},
               'dictB': None, 'dictC': None, }

lists = {f"list_{k}": [v["text"], v["confidence"]] if v else [0, 0] for k, v in
                                          nested_dict.items()}

print(lists["list_dictA"], lists["list_dictB"], lists["list_dictC"])
# output: ['ok', 'lol'] [0, 0] [0, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to create new variables, you have to assign to `globals()`.

Here's a way to do that for this dictionary:

```
for k, v in nested_dict.items():
    var_name = f"list_{k}"
    if v:
        globals()[var_name] = [v.get("text", 0), v.get("confidence", 0)]
    else: 
        globals()[var_name] = [0, 0]
    print (var_name) # just show the var name. Not needed. 

print(list_dictA)
==> ['ok', 'lol']
print(list_dictB)
==> [0, 0
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done quite efficiently with list comprehension of python:

```
nested_dict = { 'dictA': {'text': "ok",'useleskey':'useles_value','confidence': "lol"},
                'dictB':  None, 
                'dictC':  None, }
res = [[i['text'], i['confidence']] if i else [0, 0] for i in nested_dict.values()]

In [16]: res                                                                                                                                          
Out[16]: [['ok', 'lol'], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can use a dict comprehension:

```
nested_dict = { 'dictA': {'text': "ok",'useleskey':'useles_value','confidence': "lol"},
                'dictB':  None, 
                'dictC':  None, }

list_dict = {f'list_dict_{k[-1]}':[v[f] for f in v.keys() if f in ['text','confidence']] if v else [0,0] for k,v in nested_dict.items()}

print(list_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'list_dict_A': ['ok', 'lol'], 'list_dict_B': [0, 0], 'list_dict_C': [0, 0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the question mentions pandas, I am suggesting this one-line:

```py
pd.DataFrame(nested_dict).T.fillna(0).assign(info=lambda df: df[["text", "confidence"]].agg(list, axis=1))

Out: 
      confidence text     useleskey       info
dictA        lol   ok  useles_value  [ok, lol]
dictB          0    0             0     [0, 0]
dictC          0    0             0     [0, 0]
```